# SSO between native apps

Tags: android, ios, single-sign-on, saml

Is there any common pattern for doing SSO between two native mobile apps? I'm looking for something that would work on either iOS or Android.

I want something like SAML, where one server can pass an encrypted message to another. But in SAML, this works by passing a message through web forms and URLs. That wouldn't work between native apps, although I guess you could rig something up to pass a message through a custom URL scheme.

My goal is to log into one app, then click a button to launch another app, and have it log you in automatically.

Comment: I didn't post this as an answer as I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you're looking for -- and it's still emerging. http://openid.net/wg/napps/

Comment: "I guess you could rig something up to pass a msg via custom URL scheme", yes, that is your answer.  The other app needs a documented Intent (Android) or URL scheme (Android and iOS) for passing the SSO credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using any of the following approachs. All you need to do this your provisioning profile should use the same app seed Id ( same team profile)

1. UIPasteBoard
2. Keychain

Try to combine the above approach with touchId through LAcontext